# Prevent import of unmanaged classes using IJW in c#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm using an IJW layer between my C# code and a C++ framework.

C# --references--> IJW --references--> C++

My issue is that the classes inside the namespaces in the C++ code, gets imported into the C# code as -inaccessible- empty System.ValueType's. This creates a lot of false keywords in the intellisense, and gives me some nameclashes.

This could be solved by wrapping *everything* in the unmanaged C++ code in one main namespace, but I'd much prefer to avoid that solution and just.. Not, import those useless namespaces.

I made a [Minimal Working Example](https://gist.github.com/lukaspj/bbd6eb5e38ba17df8fcb), using 3 different projects in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. Where `B` and `C` is dll's and `A` is an exe. As you can see, in A.cs the `using C;` doesn't cast any errors because the namespace `C` is imported, it's just empty.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgTUt.png) is an image of the assembly in the VS2013 assembly explorer.

Edit: 
As pointed out by Hans Passant, just because the code is in an unmanaged DLL, doesn't mean it's compiled as unmanaged code.

When it's #imported into the C++/CLI dll it's compiled with /clr option i.e. managed code.

Therefore, to prevent the code from being compiled with the /clr, you have to tell the compiler that it's unmanaged code.

The necessary change to fix it in the MWE:

```cpp
// #pragma unmanaged
// push managed state on to stack and set unmanaged state
#pragma managed(push, off)

#include "Sample.h"

// #pragma managed
#pragma managed(pop)
```

I removed this as an answer as it seems this didn't fix it anyways. I thought it did, but that was because of a change I accidentally made to the source that prevented the unmanaged DLL from compiling.

Comment: Do not declare any members of the `ref class` that are of a native type as *public*.  Consider *private* or *internal* instead.

Comment: In the MWE, there is no ref class, only a native class. Thanks for replying!

Comment: If an empty namespace causes a problem then you need to pick a better name.  Use the [naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you have to.  And make sure that native code gets compiled without /clr in effect.  You don't want to have it produce MSIL.

Comment: One of the problems was that it clutters the intellisense, for no reason. Thus giving it a different name is not a complete solution. 

The thing I needed was to use #pragma managed(push, off) before including the header. Thanks for the help!